# Is this syntax for this class correct, not working correct, Script error. (: line 0) (javascript p5.js)

Tags: javascript, class, oop, object, p5.js

I am creating a class which takes an array of vectors, and then draws a leaf on the coordinates of each of the items in the array. I have wrote a class to achieve this, which takes the array of vectors as an argument int in the constructor then have a draw function. I have tried to implement this into my code however I am getting a script error and cant identify what is wrong.

The code below is the class that I am using, but this uses a getter from a class which creates a tree, the classes in combination can be found here: https://editor.p5js.org/remcqueen/sketches/rkk9QMzG4

```
class drawLeaves {

  constructor(leafArray) {
    this.leafs = leafArray
  }

  genLeaves(minDiam, maxDiam, minAlpha, maxAlpha) {
    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < this.leafs.length; i++) {
        let h = map(i, 0, this.leafs.length, minHue, maxHue);
        let s = 255;
        let b = 255;
        let a = random(minAlpha, maxAlpha);
        fill(h, s, b, a);
        let diam = random(minDiam, maxDiam);
        let jitterX = random(-30, 30);
        let jitterY = random(-30, 30);  
        ellipse(this.leafs[i].x + jitterX, this.leafs[i].y + jitterY, diam, diam);
    }
  }

  draw() {
    this.genLeaves(0, 50, 0, 0.12);  // big leaves
    this.genLeaves(0, 15, 0, 0.4);  // small leaves
  }
}
```

This class should draw leave style ellipses when the draw method is called.

Comment: In your P5 console:Uncaught ReferenceError: minHue is not defined (sketch: line 78)

Comment: You should really watch the console for error messages. This will save you a lot of fuss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `minHue` and `maxHue`

https://editor.p5js.org/HerrSerker/sketches/HkwlLfGMN

```
var p;
var l;
var minHue = 20;
var maxHue = 250;
function setup() {
 // ...
}

// ...
```

Comment: I'd probably make these constants